# Macro to move alternate row data in column B to column C alternaltely

Tags: excel, macros, vba

I am naïve to macros. I have data in column B with 500 rows of data. I need to move alternate rows of data to columns C .

```
For example, move data from 
B2 to C1, 
B4 to C3, 
B6 to C5, and so on
```

I appreciate if anyone can provide macro for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
For i =2 to 500 step 2
   Range("C" & i-1).value = Range("B" & i).value
   Range("B" & i).value = ""
Next i
```

Comment: Excellent it works. It copies the data perfectly, but the data in column B2 B4 B6 still remains there. I don't need that. Need to delete them. Please a solution to that I much appreciated.

Comment: @Siraj Ok, but looking at your history you don't accept anyones answers. So this time you first accept then I give you the last line of code you are missing

Comment: I wish, please tell how to do that.

Comment: There are three buttons on the left of each answer. One is for accept, one is to upvote and one is to downvote. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Siraj edited my answer, thank you. In my opinion you should go back to your old questions and give the people that helped you in the past the credit they deserve.

Comment: Thanks Andrea. I did accepted your answer. Honestly those three button are not visible for me. I just moved the cursor over and got the alt text and accepted. Same for all history of my answers. I will go now and accept all answers. Thanks

Comment: Try changing your screensettings then. Like gamma or contrast. It's probably one of those that make gray items disapear.

Comment: Hi Andreas, Can you please provide me the last line of code to delete.

Comment: Wonderful, it worked. Thanks a lot for solving my problem.